# Why exports fail in webpack when using an index file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

The file inside the constant file

```
export const localStorageItem = {      
  COMPANY_ID: "companyId",
  COMPANY_NAME: "companyName",
  LANDING_PAGE: "landingPage",
  LOGIN_TYPE: "loginType",
  PLATFORM_VERSION: "platformVersion",
  PLATFORM_VIEWS: "platformViews"      
};
```

The index file from the constants folder

```
...
export * from "./design.constant";
export * from "./application.constant";
export * from "./localStorage.constant";
export * from "./store-constant";
...
```

The file where the import from `@/constant` was done

```
import { localStorageItem  } from "@/constants";


export function makeFormDataObject() {
  return {
    companyId: parseInt(localStorage.getItem(localStorageItem.COMPANY_ID)),   
  };
}
```

Inside that function makeFormDataObject `localStorageItem` is undefined.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack is what we use to bundle everything together. Even is this syntax `export * from "./design.constant";` is super user-friendly sometimes it doesn't work.
When it doesn't, for the file which has the import issue, your would need to manually import and export the functions/objects.
The first export has to be the one that has the problematic entities. The other ones can remain the same.

example:

```
import { 
 localStorageItem
} from "./localStorage.constant";

export {
  localStorageItem
};

export * from "./design.constant";
export * from "./application.constant";
export * from "./store-constant";
```